# Good, authentic, not fake Poetry competitions

Tags: poetry, contests

I searched a lot on internet for real and good poetry competitions but am not able to find any which I can be sure of as being legitimate.

The writing community here may have already taken part in many such competitions and may be having through knowledge on this.

Please guide towards some actual and genuine contests.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the books on your shelf. Collections often show where their stories/poems have been published before and what competitions they've won. Same with anthologies. So you're finding the contests that your favorite authors have participated in.

Answer (score 3):

My poetry is too terrible to consider entering competitions so I can't help from personal experience! But there's a Wiki of international poetry competitions including major international awards and I would imagine that any non-legit entries would be edited, so that would be a good place to start.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poetry_awards

Victoria Strauss also writes a good page on how to spot fakes and has even tested some of these fakes to see the results. It's worth a read and may help you sort the wheat from the chaff.

http://www.victoriastrauss.com/advice/contests/

Hopefully, you'll get some personal recommendations on here but in the meantime, this should get you started.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There are three resources I would look through. [Writer's Digest](https://www.writersdigest.com) - their different market guides (Poet's Market for example) list contests as well as a big section on different publishing markets. They will list info about costs and so on. The market guides are published every year. [Poets & Writers](https://www.pw.org) I believe also lists contests. You can check their website for free. [Duotrope](https://www.duotrope.com) lists marketing information for journals, book publishers, and contests. You may need to do a bit of playing around with the search for what you want, but the Calendar lists upcoming deadlines which may be helpful.

In ALL cases, look at the publisher/contest holder website. You need to use your own discretion when checking them out. If something sounds too good to be true, it probably is. One thing to note is that a lot of contests are run by universities and probably have been running for a long time. IMO those should be safe. Contests often charge fees, so take that into account - the amount may vary.